# Check multiple rangeOfString (Swift)

Tags: string, if-statement, swift

How do I perform multiple rangeOfString's but only if the value being checked has a value?

E.g. below

```
var string1 = "hello"
var string2 = "world"

var checker1 = "he"
var checker2 = ""

if string1.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(checker1) != nil {
    println("exists1")
}
```

//SHOULD not perform below as the value below as "checker2" is empty.

```
if string2.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(checker2) != nil {
    println("exists2")
}
```

Comment: By "has a value", do you mean non-empty string?

Comment: Yes. The string will be the value that the users inputs to a UITextField so if they leave it blank i would like it to not perform the if statement. If both strings have values I would like it to perform both.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is working exactly as you want it.  Copy & pasting, this only printed "exists1" but not "exists2".  If we put a "w" for `checker2`, it prints both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a check if the string is non-empty:

```
if checker2 != "" && string2.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(checker2) != nil {
    println("exists2")
}
```

But that is actually *not necessary* because `rangeOfString()` returns `nil` if called
with an empty argument. And if you rewrite the test as

```
if string2.rangeOfString(checker2, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil {
    println("exists2")
}
```

then there is even no overhead for the `lowercaseString` conversion in the empty
string case.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:  Official documentation: `Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").`  +1